# How to reload the CSS or button or part of a page after get request is received?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, get-request

after get request arrive the values are there and the button disappear 
[image: after get request is received]

this is the button working on the localhost.. 
[image: expected presentation of the button woking ex at local host]

Im trying to add a Facebook share button in a page with dynamic contents like userid, coming from a esp826 server, using java script like innerhtml by ajax call get request once of json when the page body is on-load. When i test in my local host everything is ok since the json file load very fast and before the button loads and so everything works ok. but when i use the esp8266 server the response of the get request come somewhat after the button is loaded and so when it received and the fields get populated with the values the button disappear and remain only a word with a link.

basically the button is working on my localhost... so the innerhtml and everything is ok.. it seems i need to find a way to reload the css or something by the javascript to get the button box alive again.

is there a way to reload the button?

the .json file is just this:  getajx.json
`{"temp1":"1", "energia":"2", "energiatotal":"3", "tem":"2", "cliente":"22", "usuario":"22"}`

you can test on your localhost by placing this getajx.json file having that content in the same directory of the html page is going to work... but i need to know how to make it work if the get request get too long.. please any help???

i tried to add a flag after the response is positive and activate the reloadCss funtion with it but didnt worked

```
    <script>
var temp1, energia, energiatotal, tem, cliente, usuario ;
var ok=0;
       function GetAjx() {
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         ok = 1;
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       document.getElementById("temp1").innerHTML = myObj.temp1;
        document.getElementById("energiatotal").innerHTML = myObj.energiatotal;
        document.getElementById("tem").innerHTML = myObj.tem;

                    }};
            if (ok =1) {    function reloadCss(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for (var cl in links){
        var link = links[cl];
        if (link.rel === "stylesheet")
            link.href += "";
    }}
};  
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getajx.json" , true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi please include a screenshot of the issue and the expected results

Comment: You've defined your `reloadCss()` function but I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: i found this piece of code to try to reload but i would need it to reload after the response is already populated right?  i tried to call it after the innerhtmls but didnt seem to work too..

Comment: using the waterfall in the google chrome i can see that the get request is getting much after the button is loaded around 1000ms ... in the localhost case the getrequest get very fast 400ms

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...

apparently i had to change the order of the scripts making the jquery ajax source load first and also tried to put the script from facebook at the bottom of the page...

i took away the reload scripts and other facebook scripts i was testing

and most importantly made the get request false to make it sync instead of async this forces the page to wait for the get request finish..strangely i tried it before and didnt worked this solution perhaps because of the order of the scripts.. can anyone comment on that?

`xmlhttp.open("GET", "getajx.json" , false);`

was helpful using the f12 on google chrome in specific the performance tab

i decided to not mess up with priority of the scripts even if i tried

any comments i would appreciate

again

thanks for the help